# Matrix Multiplication Python - Matrix rows not seperated

Tags: python, matrix, multiplication

I am currently trying to do matrix mult on python and the correct answer is appearing but, instead of each row being on it's own, all the rows are combined into one row then repeated for the number of rows.

```
def matrixtranspose(m1):
    mT = [[m1[i][x] for i in range(len(m1))] for x in range(len(m1[0]))]
    return mT

def dotProduct(m1row, m2column):
    l3 = [m1row[i] * m2column[i] for i in range(len(m1row))]
    dP = sum(l3)
    return dP

def matrixmult(m1, m2):
    transposedMatrix = matrixtranspose(m2)
    numRows = len(transposedMatrix)
    newMatrix = []
    addedDP = []

    for rows in range(0, (len(m1))):
            for col in range(0, len(transposedMatrix)):
                addedDP.append(dotProduct(m1[rows], transposedMatrix[col]))
            newMatrix.append(addedDP)

    return newMatrix
```

this will return:

```
[[4, 20, 4, 4, 20, 4, 6, 36, 6],
 [4, 20, 4, 4, 20, 4, 6, 36, 6],
 [4, 20, 4, 4, 20, 4, 6, 36, 6]]
```

Instead of:

```
[[4, 20, 4] [4, 20, 4] [6, 36, 6]]
```

how could I fix it?

Comment: You should probably add how you invoke the defined methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your accretion logic:

```
addedDP = []

for row in range(0, (len(m1))):
    for col in range(0, len(transposedMatrix)):
        addedDP.append(dotProduct(m1[row], transposedMatrix[col]))
```

You are adding each element to `addedDP` as you go through the matrix: *each* product is appended to a global list of values, rather than only the values for the current row.  `addedDP` doesn't reset for each new row.  And then, for each row in the matrix:

```
    newMatrix.append(addedDP)
```

you add the original reference to the entire list.  Thus, when you finish, you have `len(m1)` copies of that list in your "result" list.

You can fix this by re-initializing `addedDP` for each row:

```
newMatrix = []

for row in range(0, (len(m1))):
    addedDP = []
    for col in range(0, len(transposedMatrix)):
        addedDP.append(dotProduct(m1[row], transposedMatrix[col]))
        # print("row, col:", row, col, addedDP)
    newMatrix.append(addedDP)
    # print("row", row, addedDP)

return newMatrix
```

I left in my debugging `print` statements.  I strongly recommend you learn this basic debugging tool: if you have an ailing program, *ask* it where things hurt!  :-)
See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Given a main program of:

```
m1 = [[1, 2],
      [3, 4]]
m2 = [[0, 1],
      [-1, 0]]
print(matrixmult(m1, m2))
```

Output with `print` statements enabled:

```
row, col: 0 0 [-2]
row, col: 0 1 [-2, 1]
row 0 [-2, 1]
row, col: 1 0 [-4]
row, col: 1 1 [-4, 3]
row 1 [-4, 3]
[[-2, 1], [-4, 3]]
```